# Blur effect on scaleX(-1) for IE 11

Tags: css, scale, internet-explorer-11

When I try to flip an image on Internet Explorer 11, it works but the flipped image loose quality and looks blurry.

```
.edit{
transform:scaleX(-1);
}
```

Try here for IE 11 : http://jsfiddle.net/uGm23/4/

Is there a way to fix the render quality with CSS or in another way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try not to use `scale(-1)`. You can rotate instead:

`-ms-transform: rotate(-180deg)`

this should result in the same effect and not be blurry...
I don't have IE11 to test this, so you have to try yourself ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, IE11 returns the same results as scaleX(-1), however I can get a near good looking image with :   -ms-transform: rotatey(200deg) rotatex(0deg); but I loose some width to the element. Guess it might be an issue in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: yeah I guess so. And btw you don't need to set `rotatex(0deg)` if it's 0 ;). Just use `rotatey(200deg)`.

Comment: Hm another try: `-ms-filter: "FlipH";`. But this might even be outdated for IE11